# MySQL (phpmyadmin) update query from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with my SQL query as I have two tables named Student_Summary and Fees_Master.  In Student Summary I have a column named Admission_fees and in fees master we have Fees_Type.  For fees type we have multiple options like admission fees, hostel fees, late fees etc...

I need some help with how to update the student_summary admission fees amount from fees master.

I want update the value from fees master to student summary with matching admission fees column (please refer two tables in below images).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle (e.g. dbfiddle.uk) with your tables' schemas, some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: I recommend lower fees.

Comment: it just a sample data, we have large numbers of data so please suggest some other solution